# Proving that $f$ is the identity function if $ \ f \circ g = g \circ f$ for all $g$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is a problem from Spivak's Calculus. I can see how it applies for some family of functions, for example, if $g$ is constant; but I need to prove it for *any* $g$.

Comment: What prevents you from still taking $g$ to be constant?

Comment: You don't need to "prove it for any $g$", the "for all $g$" part is a given, not a goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to prove anything for all $g$. The claim to prove is of the form "If all $g$ have a certain property, then something". To show this, it is enough to show the (in fact stronger) statement "If all somewhat special $g$ have a certain property, then something".

Comment: I have no idea why the simple logical structure of this problem stumped me, now that it has become clear.

Answer (score 0):

Truth is that you need to prove that for any $ f $ that is **not** the identity, there exists a $ g $ such that $ f \circ g \neq g \circ f $.  You have to construct such $ g $